Journey Builder with DE Entry contains duplicate Contacts for Reminders
We would like to create a Journey that sends a one-hour reminder email before each event starts. Since a contact can have multiple events in a day, we would like to send a separate email for each event. Our Data Extension (DE) is structured as shown below. We update this DE daily to capture all users with events scheduled for the current day.
Question: Can we use Journey Builder with a "Wait by Attribute" set to "One Hour Before Event Time" to ensure emails are sent at the exact time? Additionally, will duplicate entries for the same contact cause any issues in the Journey if we select "No Re-entry After Exit"?



Contact
Evenet
One Hour Before Event Time
Event Time




Contact 1
Event 1
2024-10-31 10:00 AM
2024-10-31 11:00 AM


Contact 1
Event 2
2024-10-31 10:30 AM
2024-10-31 11:30 AM



If above process is not working, what might be the best approach to set up the Journey so the Event 1 reminder email can be sent to Contact 1 on 10AM and Event 2 reminder email can be sent to Contact 1 on 10:30AM?
Thank you for your help!
